# How to divide RGB values for correct time of day color?

Tags: javascript, date, rgb

Not the biggest whiz on math here... having a hard time figuring this out.

So I get the clients time of day using:

```
var clientdate = new Date();                            
var clientTime = clientdate.getHours() + 1;
```

Psuedo:

```
If clientTime() = 1, rgb should equal 55,91,128
If clientTime() = 24, rgb should equal 0,30,61
```

What I am trying to figure out is how to get the values to be correct if the time is, for instance, 14.

My original theory was this:

1. Subtract difference from RGB values.
   So they would be 55,61,67.
2. Divide clientTime by 24
   (`clientTime/24`), multiple that by
   my difference in step 1.
3. Subtract step 2 from the original RGB values.

Here is the code:

```
var clientdate = new Date();                            
var clientTime = clientdate.getHours() + 1;



var r = 55;
var g = 91;
var b = 128;
var rn = 0;
var gn = 30;
var bn = 61;    

var rt = (r-rn)*(clientTime/24);
var gt = (g-gn)*(clientTime/24);
var bt = (b-bn)*(clientTime/24);

var rf = r-rt;
var gf = g-gt;
var bf = b-bt;
```

**Question**

How do I get RGB values between 55,91,128 and 0,30,61 based on the time of day.

Did I do this correctly, and if so, how do I do it more concise?

Comment: revised the question a little bit...

Comment: He's trying to interpolate between two colours based on the time of day, so for example the colour will go from blue in the morning through purple to red at night. (Not the right colours!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be inclusive of the bounds on your color, then change `clientTime` to:

```
clientdate.getHours();
```

...and change rt, gt, and bt to:

```
var rt = (r-rn)*(clientTime/23.0);
var gt = (g-gn)*(clientTime/23.0);
var bt = (b-bn)*(clientTime/23.0);
```