# Dynamic Intensity of a Color with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, colors, background-color

I've seen many people managing to work with intensity between two or three colors, but I only need one.

I have a table with a column for late dates and I only need to work with red in that case. If the date is 1 day late, it needs to be a light red and the more days go by, the more intense the color gets.

What I tried:

Note: I used the basics of Vue.js to make it easier, you don't need to have any knowledge, just copying and changing the function or creating another one and calling it you can work on it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.12"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>
  <div id="id">
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-striped w-auto">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Due Data</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <span class="badge" v-bind:style="'background-color: rgb('+255/3*getLateDays('2022-07-08')+',0,0)'">
                2022-07-08
              </span>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <span class="badge" v-bind:style="'background-color: rgb('+255/3*getLateDays('2022-07-09')+',0,0)'">
                2022-07-09
              </span>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <span class="badge" v-bind:style="'background-color: rgb('+255/3*getLateDays('2022-07-10')+',0,0)'">
                2022-07-10
              </span>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script>
  var myApp = new Vue({
    el: '#id',
    data() {
      return {

      }
    },
    methods: {
      getLateDays(date) {
        return Math.ceil((new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0) - new Date(date + ' 00:00:00').setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
      }
    },
  });
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: You'll want `255, 200, 200` (light red) for not so urgent and `255, 0, 0` (100% red) for very urgent. You're changing the red channel instead, but you need to keep red at 255 and change the other two based on the days.

Comment: Regardless of intensity, do green and white need to have the same value to keep red?

Comment: I guess you mean "green and blue". Yes, otherwise you'll move away from "pure" red (toward magenta / yellow) https://www.rapidtables.com/web/color/RGB_Color.html

Comment: I'm not able to find a calculation so I can manipulate the green and blue. Do you have any idea what it would be like?

Comment: Use something like `255 - Math.min(255, lateDays * 50)`, then plug that value into `\`rgb(255, ${val}, ${val})\``. This will give 100% red for 5+ days, less red for less days.

Comment: Wow, that was the best result!
Is it possible to give you points as best answer or something?
By the way, I have another column for future dates and I need to work in the same way but with gray color. The closer the day is, the more gray it gets and the further away, it gets lighter, almost white.
How would I handle color in this case based on days?

Comment: Medium gray is 128,128,128. White is 255,255,255. Just use something like `128 + days * 10` or something for all three channels. Here's an existing question for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514621/how-to-divide-rgb-values-for-correct-time-of-day-color